# Is the weight of a board a good proxy for moisture content?

Tags: wood-movement

I've been working out a process to mill usable lumber from some trees that fell on my property.  They are all either maple or cherry.  Most of what I've read said to allow one year of drying time per inch of thickness and I've been following that.

However, in one video I watched, then man weighed his boards on a scale and wrote down the numbers.  He said if the weight stays the same over the course of one week, then the board is ready to use.  I have not seen that repeated anywhere else, so I'm looking for second opinions. Is that a reliable way to know if I can start using my lumber for projects?

I should also mention that in my case, I'm talking about pretty small boards.  No more than 6 inches wide and a maximum of 30 inches in length, with varying thicknesses of 1 to 1.5 inches.

Comment: Short answer is that yes, you can use weight to some degree. It is typically only used in a drying context. In terms of air drying however, something I've never seen addressed is that you *can't* weigh boards over a period of only a week and then assume they're as dry as they're going to be, you have to factor in any changes in conditions that may be affecting drying rate, so for example it's possible near to fully dried that drying can cease if there were an increase in temp and RH. In fact, once boards are near to fully dried it's possible for the weight to go UP rather than down.

Comment: BTW your scales have to be quite accurate for this to be at all workable. Gram-accurate scales or better are probably a must here. In case it's not very obvious the ideal way to do this is the same way that every guide suggests, and that's getting a decent moisture meter, making sure it's well calibrated and using it properly to get reliable readings.

Comment: I presume based on the species mentioned that you're in the temperate zone? Were you aware that air-dried wood isn't really dry enough (and certainly not in the core with boards 1" thick or thicker) that you can fully trust it for interior projects in much of the US or Canada? For furniture work and similar, you generally want your wood to be around 7-9% MC (6-8% according to some sources). While with full air drying you can only get to the usually quoted range of 12-15%...... but it could be as high as 18% (!) if e.g. the wood has undergone only a single year of drying.

Answer (score 3):

one way to use weight of a board for measuring moisture content is to take a sample, weight it (accurately) put it in the oven at around 225, cook it for a while 2-3 hours? (depends on how green it is) then weigh it again.

This will tell you what was the total moisture content of the wood.
After weight/before weight.

By putting it in the oven like this it can reduce the moisture content to 0, it of course ruins the board for anything else, which is why you want a smaller sample, but it will tell you what the moisture content is. of the rest of the boards.  if it is stacked and stickered, you will probably need a couple samples from different areas.

an alternate option is to buy a moisture meter, a decent one costs less than $200 and for anyone cutting their own lumber (or having it cut for them) a moisture meter is worth every penny.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed true that wood will lose mass as you dry the moisture out. Conversely, water loss is the main component of any mass difference - there are not many other ways that wood can spontaneously loose mass through.

Keep in mind that things like the resin coming out or insects attacking part of the wood could cause a weight reduction as well. However, realistically these shouldn't be too common.

You quote someone who uses the *differential* of mass as a proxy. In fact, the water weight percentage will decrease asymptotically, so the wood will never truly stop losing mass. But of course the differential will generally decay over time, so there will surely come a point where the decrease over unit time is too small for your measuring device and/or patience, and you can take that as the point it's "done". This seems like a pretty reliable way, assuming your scale is sensitive enough that the initial mass loss is very obvious.

You can get around low sensitivity by weighing multiple boards together, but then it will be harder to detect if one of the boards in a batch happened to not dry while the rest did. Analog scales, like balances will usually measure much more accurately than digital.

Also, keep in mind that for freshly cut wood used in construction (log houses) usually people dry it at least 1-2 years. So if you take measurements over a short time it might be hard to detect. Multiple weeks apart would be more sensitive.

When wood "dries", it does not actually dry completely. Rather, its moisture content approaches some equilibrium point that depends on ambient moisture (whether that is higher or lower). The rate at which it gains or loses moisture is proportional to how far away it is from the equilibrium (and temperature) which is where you get the asymptote. In a kiln, you have almost zero ambient moisture, and also high temperature, so you can get a lot of moisture out, but watch out for some of that coming back in a humid room.

People concerned about moisture usually get moisture meters (they measure electrical properties of the wood). The local lumber yard might let you use theirs if you ask nicely (maybe you bring the boards to them so you don't have to borrow the meter). Another trick I heard is to leave the stock in whatever room/environment it will be used for a few weeks, before starting to work. That way your project will have been made of wood already be close to equilibrium, and won't move as much when you finish it.

Comment: *"Analog scales, like balances will usually measure much more accurately than digital."* Exqueese me?? Can't remember the last time I saw an analogue scale used in a lab-type setting, excepting autopsy scales.